# numpy timedelta64 not showing fraction

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, timedelta

I want to convert 847hours into days, Actual result is 847/24= 35,29..

But, numpy show only "35 days"

---

```
import numpy as np

x= np.timedelta64(847, 'h')

x= np.timedelta64(x, 'D')

print(x) #Returns 35 days, Expected 35,29
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of a `timedelta64` is always stored as *a 64-bit integer* (cf. [Datetime Units](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)). To obtain fractional days, we can do:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.timedelta64(847, 'h')
x = x / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
print(x)
```

The result `35.291666666666664` is inevitably no longer a `timedelta64`.

Comment: Actually, that was gonna be my second question :) I was gonna ask how can i have a float!! Thank you