# How to add fractional days using timedelta64?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

```
t0 = np.datetime64(datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
t0 + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

This is the output:

```
numpy.datetime64('2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000')
```

I want to add fractional days:

```
t0 + np.timedelta64(1.379, 'D')
```

Above command gives the error

> ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta

Is there a simple way to add fractional days?

Comment: Have you tried adding it as 1985 minutes?

Comment: I guess I should add the original motivation for the post was that I have a long array of values like this, all referenced to some date (t0 in my example). Is there a way to directly add them without first converting into minutes? [For matlab users, I am trying to mimic what the datenum function does there.]

Comment: related: [numpy timedelta64 not showing fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866244/numpy-timedelta64-not-showing-fraction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17408); numpy timedeltas have an internal integer representation, and they expect you to pick appropriate units to have integer values.  But the standard datetime module can do this:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0) + dt.timedelta(days=1.379)
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 9, 5, 45, 600000)
```

pandas also has a `Timedelta` that supports this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 9, 5, 45, 600000)
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 9, 5, 45, 600000)

# or using the pandas.Timestamp
>>> pd.Timestamp('01-01-2000') + pd.Timedelta(1.379, 'D')
Timestamp('2000-01-02 09:05:45.600000')
```

You can convert any of these back to numpy datetime if you want:

```
>>> np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp('01-01-2000'))
numpy.datetime64('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000')

>>> np.datetime64(datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0))
numpy.datetime64('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000')
```

Otherwise,you need to convert your timedelta to new units (getting as precise as you want to be; in this case, milliseconds gives you the same answer):

```
>>> days = 1.379
>>> milliseconds = days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
>>> np.datetime64(datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0)) + np.timedelta64(int(milliseconds), 'ms')
numpy.datetime64('2000-01-02T09:05:45.600000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to making use of `datetime.timedelta` or `pandas.Timestamp` as mentioned in the accepted answer you can also add precision with `.astype`:

```py
t0 + 1.379 * np.timedelta64(1, 'D').astype('timedelta64[s]')
```